# Memory status when thread was being aborted in multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I didn't find a relevant search hit about what will happen to the memory a thread is using when is it being aborted, if it is a multi-threaded application.

Will there will any memory leak?

Also, if I didn't call `Thread.ResetAbort()` in `catch` clause will exception `ThreadAbortException` be thrown to the outer catch and outer catch if any...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Threads do not use memory. Processes have memory. Threads run in their parent process.
- In C# objects allocated by an object are not different depending which thread has allocated them. Read up on garbage collection.

> Also, if I didn't call Thread.ResetAbort() in catch clause will exception 
>   ThreadAbortException be thrown to the outer catch and outer catch if any...

There is something called a documentation and this is a VERY simple lookup there. Let me quote for you. All I did was type "ThreadAbortException" into google, which leads me to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Now the quote:

> When a call is made to the Abort method to destroy a thread, the
>   common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException.
>   ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block. When
>   this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks
>   before ending the thread. Because the thread can do an unbounded
>   computation in the finally blocks or call Thread.ResetAbort to cancel
>   the abort, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end. If you
>   want to wait until the aborted thread has ended, you can call the
>   Thread.Join method. Join is a blocking call that does not return until
>   the thread actually stops executing.

Simple like that. It automatically is rethrown at the end of the catch.